# Occasional stuttering with SceneKit when touching the screen

Tags: swift, rendering, scenekit

When I interact with the screen the objects in my game start to stutter. My FPS is at 60 and doesn't drop but the stuttering is still prevalent. I believe my problem is how I'm animating the objects on screen(code below).If anybody could help I would appreciate it.

I have an x amount of nodes inside an array called _activePool. In the Update function I am moving the nodes x position inside _activePool, adding new nodes when the last node in _activePool position is <= 25 and removing the first node in _activePool if it's position is <= -25.

```
if _cycleIsActive{

            for obj in _activePool{
                //move the obj in _activePool
                obj.position.x += Float(dt * self.speedConstant);
            }

            let lastObj = _activePool.last;

            if (lastObj?.position.x)! + getWidthOfNode(node: lastObj!) + Float(random(min: 15, max: 20)) <= 25{

                // get new obj(pattern) and add to _activePool
                self.getPatternData(sequencePassedIn: selectedSeq, level: self._currentLevel, randomPattern: randomPattern());
            }

            let firstObj = _activePool.first;

            if (firstObj?.position.x)! + getWidthOfNode(node: firstObj!) <= -25{

                // remove object and return to specific pool
                firstObj?.removeFromParentNode();
                returnItems(item: firstObj!);

                _activePool.removeFirst();
            }
        }
```

I create several arrays and add them to a dictionary

```
          func activatePools(){
    temp1Pool = ObjectPool(tag: 1, data: []);
    dictPool[(temp1Pool?.tag)!] = temp1Pool;

    temp2Pool = ObjectPool(tag: 2, data: []);
    dictPool[(temp2Pool?.tag)!] = temp2Pool;

    for i in 0... dictPool.count {
         obstacleCreationFactory(factorySwitch: i);
    }

}
```

Creating my obstacles(enemies)

```
 func obstacleCreationFactory(factorySwitch: Int){
        Enemies = Enemy();

        switch factorySwitch {
        case 0:
            for _ in 0...100{
                let blueEnemy = Enemies?.makeCopy() as! Enemy
                blueEnemy.geometry = (Enemies?.geometry?.copy() as! SCNGeometry);
                blueEnemy.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue;
                blueEnemy.tag = 1;
                temp1Pool?.addItemToPool(item: blueEnemy);

            }
        case 1:
            for _ in 0...100{
                let redEnemy = Enemies?.makeCopy() as! Enemy
                redEnemy.geometry = (Enemies?.geometry?.copy() as! SCNGeometry);
                redEnemy.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red;
                redEnemy.tag = 2;
                temp2Pool?.addItemToPool(item: redEnemy);
            }
        default:
            print("factory error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to look at the rest of your code base it’s really difficult to guess what would be causing your issue.

If somewhere you are creating a ton of temporary objects in a loop somewhere, you might consider creating a local autorelease pool to prevent memory spikes. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsautoreleasepool) is a good article that describes why in some situations it’s a good idea.

You could also be calling some particularly expensive functions on a timer or something. It’s difficult to say.

In short, you should consider using Xcode’s Profiling tools (called Instruments). Specifically I would recommend using Time Profiler to examine what functions are taking the most time and causing those spikes.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/418/) is a great WWDC session video that shows how you can use the time profiler, I’d recommend regularly profiling your app, especially when you have an issue like this.

Comment: I have several arrays(object pools) which are holding a large amount of objects. These objects are hidden until they get added to the _activePool and once they return to the array they become hidden again. I suspect this may be causing the problem. I've isolated my code so not much else is going on.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is how SceneKit works out of the box. If I have one node being animated back and forth through the update function, once I swipe the screen the stuttering happens. I hope someone can correct me.